# Centrality measures in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

if I have a weight for each edge, can I calculate the Betweness and Closeness using the weights or the algorithm takes each edge with weight 1? This is specifically related to Neo4j
Thanks. Vlad

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j's [Betweenness Centrality](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/labs-algorithms/betweenness-centrality/#labs-algorithms-betweenness-centrality-support) and [Closeness Centrality](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/labs-algorithms/closeness-centrality/#labs-algorithms-closeness-centrality-support) algorithms currently do not support weighted edges.